# Can't export object made with CSV mesh importer to unity

Tags: rendering, mesh, unity

[image]

So I've used the CSV Mesh importer which is a third party add-on to create an object based on various X,Y,Z values.

However not only I can't render this object, I don't know how to modify it and when I save it as .blend and try to import it to unity, it shows nothing.

This is basically some vertices and edges.

I'm very new to blender so any help would be appreciated.

I like to be able to change the color and thickness and all, but can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object has no faces. Blender cannot render single edges or vertices. You can try either the skin modifier, or press alt-c and convert to curve and use the bevel option.